# How many different colors can a normal human distinguish?

Tags: human-eye, color

I am not talking about asking a person to sit for 10 hours to separate one color. I want to know is the normal person in a normal life.  How many different colors can a normal human separate?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? Do you mean "distinguish"? If so what has sitting for 10 hours to do with it. Please clarify your question, indicate its relevance to biology and why you wish to know something like this. See the Help on ["How to ask a good question"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Right. Distinguish. From biological point of view, each human can classify 10 millions of color. However, that is not usual. People may need to take very long to classify between two very close color. That situation is not a normal situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal human" and "separate"?  A lot of it is simply training: If you include say interior decorators as normal humans, they can separate and give names to perhaps dozens of shades lke bone, eggshell, cream, ivory, linen and ecru, that most of us just call off-white.

Comment: For example, a jpg image use RGB with 256 color intensity. A total of 16.78 millions of combination.  Note, those are color intensity not color depth. But this gives us the general idea of human can separate will be less than color depth X light intensity = 16.78 million combination, because computer monitor are normally used. I want to know about the color depth of human vision in normal use!!

Comment: Values like this are determined via careful psychophysical experiments in the lab. You're asking about 'everyday life' or something? You need to carefully define what you are after then. This question is unclear, open to debate and as a consequence opinion-based and therefore offtopic in its current format.

Comment: I remember trying to find research on this subject some years ago, and the best data I could find said the range of human color vision was about 10,000,000 colors. Unfortunately, the article (which I cannot now find) didn't say how this number was reached, but I believe it was based on the response curves of the cones and didn't take into consideration whether or not the brain combines input from the cones as well as the rods to determine colors, which I believe it does. If anyone finds some definitive research, I'd find it very interesting. And I do not think this question is off-topic.

Comment: Just to correct a comment from the poster. The 16.8 million colours that can be represented in an 8-bit RGB image tell you nothing about human colour perception. (And colour intensity — whatever its relevance here — is the extent of difference from grey.) The jpeg algorithm reduces image size by reducing the number of colour on the basis that the human eye cannot distinguish (or does not notice) the difference between very similar RGB values. Although the basis of the answer to your question will be biological, your question isn't really biology in terms of SE Biology.

Comment: @David It is a biology question. I think that you do not live in USA because your colour has an 'u'. What is the traffic light color in your country? Almost all traffic light in the world have red color, it is because red trigger warning signal in the brain. My 2 hours ago comment was to use an approach to explain to people a possible direction of thinking. We could have different angle to analyze a problem.

Comment: Interestingly the answer appears to vary by culture, A lot like sounds it appears it is partially effected by what colors people are taught to distinguish between. http://imbs.uci.edu/~kjameson/ECST/Kay_Cook_WorldColorSurvey.pdf

Comment: I may not be in the US, but I live in the country where traffic lights were first [introduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light). My point is that you could ask the average speed of a cheeta and get an answer, but the question isn't really what we are after on SE Biology. That would be a question of the type, "Why is a cheeta faster than a horse?", where a useful answer would be in terms of body structure, musculator or whatever. Likewise, the question of *how* we discriminate millions of colours is much more pertinent than whether it is 1 million or 10 million.

Comment: @ Giordano Fearghas: The use of 8-bit color depth in JPEG & mainstream computer displays isn't really linked to how many colors a human can distinguish, but on hardware considerations.  8 bits fit in a byte, 3 color bytes plus an alpha (transparency) channel in a 32-bit word.  Increase color depth, and you double the amount of memory & bandwidth needed. making your system uncompetitive except for special purposes.  (Especially in the past, when memory &c was much more expensive.)  Nowadays greater depth is sometimes used: many digital cameras can do HDR (High Dynamic Range) photographs.